# Remote access OVH SQL database from Golang API

Tags: sql, database, go, ovh

I'm making a Golang API to be able to interact with a SQL database from my Android application. The problem I have is the following:

I have a sql database hosted on https://phpmyadmin.ovh.net/

I'm trying to connect my locale API to this one. According to the documentation:

```
func Open(driverName, dataSourceName string) (*DB, error)
```

The driverName params would be "mysql" isn't it?
But, what would be the **dataSourceName** params?

I saw lot of post about Open, however, I don't think I understand how to organize the url string about the dataSourceName params.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

var db *sql.DB // global variable to share it between main and the HTTP handler

func main() {

fmt.Println("starting up")

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "????????????")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error on initializing database connection: %s", err.Error())
}

err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error on opening database connection: %s", err.Error())
}

http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Thank for read & help !

**/!\ EDIT /!\**

So, after your both answers, I tried the code below:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net/http"
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type databaseinfos struct {
user string
password string
name string
address string
port string
url string
}

var db *sql.DB // global variable to share it between main and the HTTP handler
var dbi *databaseinfos

func main() {

dbi := databaseinfos{
    user: "Emixam23",
    password: "",
    name: "mydb",
    address: "127.0.0.1",
    port: "3306",
    url: ""}
dbi.url = (dbi.user + ":" + dbi.password + "@tcp(" + dbi.address + ":" + dbi.port + ")/" + dbi.name)

fmt.Println(dbi.url)

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbi.url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error on initializing database connection: %s", err.Error())
}

err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error on opening database connection: %s", err.Error())
}

/*http.HandleFunc("/", hello)*/
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

However, I got an error which is "Error on opening database connection: %s dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.".

Does the problem comes because of my computer or because of the **dataSourceName** params?

Comment: You will also need to import a MySQL driver: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

Comment: Thank for your answer

Comment: You are getting the error ('No connection could be made') because the MySQL instance on your server is not accepting connections. Check that it is running, and see if you can connect with the command line tool from the same machine `mysql -u <username> -p<password> -h <host> <database>`

Answer (score 1):

**dataSourceName** should be provided in the DSN format:

```
<username>:<password>@tcp(<host>:<port>)/<database>
```

For example:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "myuser:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb")
```

Comment: Thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in your code, here:

```
dbi.url = (dbi.user + ":" + dbi.password + "@tcp(...
```

This way of building the connection string with the parameters I see above will result in:

`Emixam23:@tcp..`.

With an empty password, which is wrong if we look at the spec:

```
[username[:password]@][protocol[(address)]]/dbname[?param1=value1&...&paramN=valueN]
```

We see that if no password is required you must not add the ":"

If the problem persists and the connection string actually matches the correct pattern, test that you can access your DB:

```
mysql -u Emixam23
```

or with password:

```
mysql -u Emixam23 -p
```

Then try to access the database to see if your user has the proper pemissions:

```
> USE mydb; SELECT 1;
```

If you can't even connect:

Check that your port and IP binding are correct:

```
sudo netstat -antp | grep mysql
```

If not, edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` accordingly.

Comment: Ok thank for your answer. But how can I create a local db under win10 if I want to test in local?

Comment: Ah, I figured you were already running that locally, then I guess the connection string password is not the problem unless your remote DB has no password which would be kinda unsafe. I never use windows for working (i find it horrible TBH) so I can't help you there sorry.